# Testing executables using rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd

Is there any way i can test a generic executable using rspec?
I like the way tests are defined in rspec.

Something along the lines of

```
it "should return error" do
    program.output.should == "Error in program"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Rspec 3.0 output matcher:

`expect { its_my_mthd }.to output("its the message for the world").to_stdout`
`expect { its_my_mthd }.to output("its devils message error").to_stderr`

Minitest also has something called capture_io:

```
out, err = capture_io do
  my_method
end

assert_equals "its the message for the world", out
assert_equals "its devils message error", err
```

Comment: what is its_my_mthd? and how do i specifiy arguments for my system command?

Comment: This will also work with shell commands executed within backticks.